# Using GROUP BY or DISTINCT with a LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, group-by, left-join

I have a table with orders and a table with users. It's possible for an order to be placed with an entry in the user table.

With the following MySQL statement I get duplicate values for orders if there is a matching user:

```
SELECT o.id, u.id as 'user_id', u.name
FROM orders o
LEFT JOIN users u ON o.user_id = u.id
WHERE o.status = 'active'
```

If I add a `GROUP BY o.id` it solves the issue.

```
SELECT o.id, u.id as 'user_id'
FROM orders o
LEFT JOIN users u ON o.user_id = u.id
WHERE o.status = 'active'
GROUP BY o.id
```

It also works if I use `SELECT DISTINCT`.

My questions are:

1. Why does it return duplicate fields?
2. Is it more correct to use GROUP BY or SELECT DISTINCT?

Comment: GROUP BY is  correct

Comment: Use group by  to get accurate results

Comment: Why will `select distinct` be wrong or not accurate?(In response to Rahautos and Ushma Shah)

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT` is faster. But the real problem is somewhere else: you have duplicate entries in the `order` table. `order.id` should be the `PK` of the table or, at least, an `UNIQUE INDEX`. Or the rows of table `orders` contain information about both the orders and the items they contain. If this is the case you should split it into two tables: one to contain the information about orders (id, date, user etc) and another one to contain the products of each order (having `order.id` as `FK`).

Comment: The `order.id` is a primary key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your *detail* query -- the query returning every row, rather than the deduplicated version with DISTINCT or GROUP BY -- is finding more than row in `users` matching each row in `orders`. So, it is dutifully returning all those rows.

To solve your problem correctly you need to figure out why there are multiple `users` rows for each order.  That is, for some values of `order.user_id` there are multiple values of `users.id`.

That seems a little strange to me, but I do not understand your data model. You probably need to get to investigate this data anomaly. A conventional schema would have each user able to place multiple orders, but each order relating to only one user. In that schema this query would yield one row per order but still include users with no orders:

```
SELECT u.id AS user_id, o.id AS order_id
  FROM users AS u
  LEFT JOIN orders AS o ON o.user_id = u.id
```

Could it be that is what you want?

Contrary to some peoples' belief, `GROUP BY orders.id` and `SELECT DISTINCT orders.id, users.id` are *not* the same thing. In fact, your proposed use of `GROUP BY` misuses the [notorious MySQL extension to `GROUP BY`.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html) Standard SQL will reject your `GROUP BY`. It will only accept `GROUP BY orders.id, users.id`, which is indeed equivalent to DISTINCT.

Answer (score 0):

> Why does it return duplicate fields?

It returns duplicates because you have not applied anything to stop it from doing so. When you apply GROUP BY or DISTINCT then you actually stop the duplicates.

> Is it more correct to use GROUP BY or SELECT DISTINCT

Both are equivalent and can be used as per your convenience. You may find that DISTINCT is faster over GROUP BY under the fact that indexes are not created on your table. But that does not make the usage of GROUP BY incorrect. If indexes are created then they both are equivalent to each other.

Answer (score 0):

Your query does not need a `JOIN` at all.  You can just use:

```
SELECT o.id, o.user_id
FROM orders o
WHERE o.status = 'active';
```

As for `SELECT DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY`.  The two should be equivalent in performance (or very close).  They are doing essentially the same work.

The advantage of `GROUP BY` is that you can add aggregation functions.  The advantage of `DISTINCT` is that you don't have to list all the columns twice, and it accepts `*`.

Comment: Thanks you are correct based on the statement in my question. I slimmed the query down to make it more readable but it does request additional values from the user table.